# How to convert customize string data to json and get the data one by one

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, unity-game-engine

This is my string data:

`[1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,3]`

I converted my string data into json and I did it like this

```
string jsonString = "[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]";
private void Start()
{
    ExampleClass dataParser = new ExampleClass();
    dataParser.dataToParse = jsonString;

    //Convert to Json
    string exampleClassToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(dataParser);
    Debug.Log(exampleClassToJson);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string dataToParse;
}
```

and it is succesfully converted here is the output of that:

`{"dataToParse":"[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]"}`

now my problem is how can I get those data one by one can I do it? Could someone help me please.

What I am trying to achieve here is to make a ScoreBoard something like this

[Image here](https://wizardofodds.com/games/images/baccarat/bac-display-bigroad-1034x176.jpg)

The red circle is my `"2"` and the blue circle is my `"1"` in my string data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really possible. Loop through the `dataToParse` variable. Make sure that the loop starts from `1` stead of `0`. Also make sure that the loop ends with `dataToParse.Length - 1` instead of `dataToParse.Length;`.  This will remove the `[` and `]`.

In the loop increment the counter by `3` instead of the usual `1`. By doing this, it will also remove the "," and " " that is placed after each value in the json. You can obtain each value as a `char` in the loop which can be converted to any value type you wish.

```
ExampleClass obj = JsonUtility.FromJson<ExampleClass>(exampleClassToJson);
//Loop over it
for (int i = 1; i < obj.dataToParse.Length - 1; i += 3)
{
    char indivisualChar = obj.dataToParse[i];

    Debug.Log(indivisualChar);
}
```

While this should solve the problem in your question, I suggest you use array or list to represent this data unless you have a good reason to do it like this then go for it.

Comment: It should work out of the box if you just copy and paste it at the **end** of the `Start` function. The one in your question....

Comment: Wow . Thank you :) (y)

Answer (score 2):

Change the json from :

```
 {"dataToParse":"[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]"}
```

to

```
 {"dataToParse": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1] }
```

Then change the class to this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ExampleClass
{
    public List<int>dataToParse;
}
```

You can access by index or iteration:

```
foreach(int i in dataToParse)
{ 
      int temp = i;
      CreateScore(temp); 
}
```

EDIT: 
Based on your last comment about how to convert the json string, I would let the system handle it and keep it simple.

Create an instance of your ExampleClass and fill the values. Then let the JsonUtility do the rest.

```
void Start()
{
      ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
      ec.dataToParse = new List<int>(){1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1};
      string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(ec);
}
```

Comment: How can i change my this `{"dataToParse":"[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]"}` to this `{"dataToParse": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1] }` ? I'm declaring it from the top sir..